Insulating a cavity for plumbing stack
Bought a new build home in Ontario in 2016. Every year when the temps go below -25, inevitably the water supply to the front half of the house freezes.
Based on what I see, it appears that the builder neglected to insulate the cavity that the stack for the half of the house goes through.
We reported the issue to them before, they came and thawed out the pipes and put some insulation around where the freeze was but then the problem persisted the following year.
I reached out to the customer service team with the builder and they said it’s too far past their warranty period to deal with.
Can I push some batt insulation in from the basement in the hopes that it’ll force its way up and fill the cavity? The cavity is between the semi-insulated (walls are but the door isn’t) garage and our interior walls.

Can you run some heat tape along the pipes?

Firstly, you don't want to fill the cavity. You want to insulate the cavity's wall(s) facing the cold side. You want to allow heat from the warm side to heat the pipes. There's a common misconception that wrapping an inanimate thing with fuzz makes it warmer. It doesn't. It just slows down the rate at which it cools.
Then, it's hard to give specific advice without eyes on it, but the keys are admitting heat and retaining it. Think that through and do what needs to be done to raise the temperature of the space by letting warm air in and preventing heat from conducting through to the garage.
My suspicion is that the cavity itself isn't insulated, but the actual exterior wall is. I could be wrong, of course, but if that's true, simply opening it to more airflow from the heated space might solve your problem.
As far as pushing batts... a thin stick or rod does wonders. The insulation needs to be in contact with the wall covering and shouldn't have gaps at the sides.
